# Comparing Blobstore and Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore, google-cloud-storage

For a GAE application, what are the tradeoffs between using the Blobstore and GCS?

- as of Aug 2015, the price of blobstore and GCS are the same ($0.312 per GB year)
- GCS has a nicer code interface (data referenced by things that look like file paths)
- GCS has console commands and a web UI for uploading/accessing data

Are there some kind of advantages to Blobstore that I'm missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Blobstore versus Google cloud storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671182/google-blobstore-versus-google-cloud-storage)

Comment: Note: as of Aug 2015 the price of blobstore and GCS are the same: $0.026 GB/month.

Answer (score 1):

Right now with my startup we are using the Blobstore service and we are planning to move to GCS. The only "drawback" I see is that you will not be able anymore to resize and crop images directly from the path ([Transforming_Images_from_the_Blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/overview#Transforming_Images_from_the_Blobstore)) .

In order to not brake all the client-side code we are thinking about an internal servlet that resize on-the-fly with a CDN in front of that in order to cache the most recent jobs.

Comment: Python version support loading Image from GCS (including get_serving_url) https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/imageclass#Image

Comment: Why are you moving from blobstore to GCS? Any technical reason behind it?

Comment: The three reason listed in the question are our main concerns. Moreover in the last months Java supports servingUrl for GCS, so the request doesn't pass anymore from our instances! In the end I have the feeling that Blobstore is something that is not anymore improved so it will be deprecated soon

Comment: @MicheleOrsi is GCS.servingUrl the same as Blobstore.createUploadUrl? I have been using [createUploadUrl](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Uploading_a_blob) alot and it is my main reason for not changing from Blobstore to GCS yet. Especially the multiform feature, where I can upload multiple files to Blobstore and then get notified in AppEngine when they have been uploaded. Is that feature available in GCS?