# Handling image content in gae web application

Tags: image, google-app-engine, jsf, primefaces, google-cloud-datastore

I am building a new web application. I use google appengine , jsf2, primefaces , java technologies for building this web application. I have to build a dynamic image gallery within this web application. ie registered users should be able to load images to a gallery and then it should be available for viewing by the public.

My issue is that : 
 1) app engine allows only a maximum of 1mb file to be written to its blob store at a time.
 2) app engine doesn't allow to write to the server file system.
 3) Should I store each image as a blob to the gae database?. But if I do that the whole application will be damn slow as there can be a lot of images. So reading the images from the blob store can make it slow and will cost heaps of processing power.

Am really confused about a proper solution and couldn't find any proper recommendation in the web. I am pretty sure that there will be a descent solution available !

It would be a great help if some one with prior experience in building web application's which deals with a lot of image content could advice me a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use [upload URLs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreService#createUploadUrl%28java.lang.String,%20com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.UploadOptions%29) when users are uploading images, so that they get uploaded directly to the Blobstore:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Uploading_a_blob

Then just reference the blobs directly via [`getServingUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ImagesService#getServingUrl%28com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey,%20int,%20boolean%29) rather than having your application try to read them into memory.

Comment: hi amber, thanks for the response. As per my understanding blobstore has a size limitation of 1mb/file. how is using blobstore better than the above suggested solution of using GCS(google cloud storage)

Comment: Blobstore is not limited to 1mb/file and hasn't been since 2011. GCS is a perfectly fine option if you want to use it, though you won't get the free 5GB of quota that comes with Blobstore.

Answer (score 0):

You really should use GCS (Google Cloud Storage), and not the blobstore.  The call from a users browser to an image stored in GCS goes directly to there, and is not charged to your app.

Comment: hi @GAEfan, thanks for the quick response. What are the benefits of using GCS instead of blobstore.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671182/google-blobstore-versus-google-cloud-storage. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175510/comparing-blobstore-and-google-cloud-storage

Comment: Blobstore also has upload urls that go directly ro blobstore