# appengine backup to GCS versus blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

What is the difference between backing up my entities to the Google Blob store versus to Google Cloud Storage? There does not seem to have much explanation on the differences.

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671182/google-blobstore-versus-google-cloud-storage?rq=1 can be of help

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, now that they both have the same basic quota and paid limitations, I don't think there is much of a difference between both. It's going to be mostly how you access/do calls on both.

For the blobstore, there is a nifty API (in [Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/) or in [Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/))

For Google Cloud Storage, you need to get the client library and add it to your project before using it (again, in [Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/) or in [Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/))

At this point, it mostly has to do with my own experience, but if all you do is store files and retrieve them, I prefer the blobstore API to the GCS client library (easier to use, I find).

In terms of cost.... the GCS will be cheaper (they both provide the same free size, and the same price per storage, but blobstore charges more for calls).

I do believe that in the backend they are VERY similar, so the difference is mostly in how you pay for them/what you need to setup to