# GAE Python webapp2 image upload error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore, webapp2

I am working on a project in which i am trying to upload a image on blob store. But i am getting this error

> File "C:\Users\shaizi\PycharmProjects\simpletestapp\Update.py", line 
>   51, in post
>
> blob_info = upload_files[0]
>   IndexError: list index out of range

My html form code is

```
<form id="signup" method="post" action="/update" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <label>Change image:</label>
        <input type="file" name="pict" ><br>
</form>
```

Python Code for uploading image to Blob store:

```
def post(self):

    blobstore.create_upload_url('/post/signup')

    upload_files = self.get_uploads('pict')

    blob_info = upload_files[0]
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `self.get_uploads`?

Comment: Its a built in function to upload the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i have to set the action to Upload url.

```
<form id="signup" method="post" action="/post/signup" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <label>Change image:</label>
        <input type="file" name="pict" ><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a `form_url` variable:

```
`   <form method="post" action="{{ form_url }}" accept-charset="UTF-8"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data">`
```

You get this variable from the appengine with your backend code:

```
class UploadPage(BaseRequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        form = UploadForm()
        self.render('upload.html', {
                'form': form,
                'form_url': blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload_form'),
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with multi-part forms, I am getting file data as follows:

```
self.request.get('<name_in_form>')
```

For your case, it should be:

```
self.request.get('pict')
```

In any case, if possible, try to avoid using blobstore, as Google recommends using Cloud Storage, as blobstore looks like will be deprecated in the future, couple of references:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/

[Google Blobstore versus Google cloud storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671182/google-blobstore-versus-google-cloud-storage)

Regards.