# Load large static assets from Google Cloud Storage bucket into new datastore entity

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

I've spent a few hours trying to figure out the best practice here and I'm still coming up empty. It's possible I'm just phrasing the question wrong since this must be out there. Nevertheless...

I have a bucket in Google Cloud Storage. Large **static asset files** are uploaded there from various sources. I don't control the upload (e.g. I can't insist on upload via blobstore api, etc). Size of each individual file is in the range of 10MB-100MB

I have an app engine app that I want to run a cron job to **check for any new uploads** to the GCS bucket, and then **create a new Cloud Datastore entity that correlates to the new asset that's been uploaded to GCS**.

In other areas of my app I have jobs that will need a **bucket reference url** to the large file to hand off to other cloud APIs.

Is the best approach to...

- Just store a reference to the URL of the Cloud Storage asset?
- Load the file from Cloud Storage into Datastore as a blob? Using ndb.blobstore? (If so, I'm a bit vague on how to automate this; the docs seem focused on calling blobstore at time of upload, not as a batch process)
- Something else? A Data Flow pipeline?

**Essentially I'm looking for the best practice for taking a collection of large assets in Cloud Storage that I don't control the upload of, and loading them into a datastore database in gae as one of several properties, according to some custom ndb entity definition. With the future ability to pass a bucket reference to an asset for further process via other APIs.**

Again, apologies if this answer is already out there, but I was hitting a wall and thought I would post here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you probably want to use a Pub/Sub (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications) that listens to the change on the storage. Either an app engine or dataflow API can be used to process the file and add entity to datastore (you can keep the url link but it is probably your call to process the asset and save its metadata somehow in your datastore). Here is a link to use Pub/Sub + app engine. https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/use-cloud-pubsub-cloud-storage-app-engine

Comment: That tutorial is extremely helpful for my case. Really appreciate it. Looks like the code uses blobstore API directly. Do you know if that's fine? On the API page (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/blobstore/) it says "You should consider using Google Cloud Storage rather than Blobstore for storing blob data" but doesn't go into much detail...

Comment: My understanding is that google is promoting/favoring Google Cloud Storage other than blobstore. If you are developing a new application rather than maintaining a legacy app, better to consider GCS. Btw, see speedplan's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671182/google-blobstore-versus-google-cloud-storage

Comment: Hey @greeness you have already answered this question, would you like to compile it all into an answer?

Comment: sure. added as an answer.

Comment: I've dug into this a bit more and can confirm that this approach is working extremely well for my use case. Accepting your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want to use a [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications) that listens to the change on the storage. Either an app engine or dataflow API can be used to process the file and add entity to datastore (you can keep the url link but it is probably your call to process the asset and save its metadata somehow in your datastore). Here is a [link](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/use-cloud-pubsub-cloud-storage-app-engine) to use Pub/Sub + app engine.

Regarding Cloud Storage vs Blobstore, my understanding is that google is promoting/favoring Google Cloud Storage other than blobstore. If you are developing a new application rather than maintaining a legacy app, better to consider GCS. Btw, see speedplan's answer here: [Google Blobstore versus Google cloud storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671182/google-blobstore-versus-google-cloud-storage).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to using PubSub, you can use a [cloud function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) with GCS to call your function when each object is finalized.

Comment: Thanks Jim. This is another solution I'm looking in to for more of a microservices architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add the following points to the previous answers:

- Datastore entities are only upto [1MiB-4bytes](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits) in size
- In Datastore Blob entities are [1 MiB - 89 bytes](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#blob)
- For big blobs, such as images Google [recommends](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview#other_storage_options) to use Google Cloud Storage
- Google has a [tool](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-blobstoremigrator-python) for migrating blobs from Blobstore to Google Cloud Storage.